Black Hole Superradiance
Could someone explain what black hole superradiance is exactly and how it extracts energy and angular momentum? What is the role of the ergoregion in this process?

On SE generally, posters are expected t ask one question per posts.  This is to keep questions and answered focused, in line with the general format and purpose of the site.
